# Remove Notification from Notification area once it is clicked

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am displaying a notification whenever a new message is received that contains particular keywords. I have used following code to show the notification in the notification area,

```
String contentTitle = "V-Card Received"; 
String contentText = "You have reeived a new V-Card"; 
 mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, receiveVCard.class);
 notificationIntent.putExtra("sender", sender);
notificationIntent.putExtra("vCardString", messages[i].getDisplayMessageBody());
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
int icon = R.drawable.contactvcard;
CharSequence tickerText = "V-Card Received";
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
notifyDetails = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, pendingIntent); 
mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails); 
notifyDetails.flags =Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Now I want to remove the notification once the user clicks on it. I Have used `Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL` to cancel the notification. But it is not removing the notification even if the user clicks on it. Is there any other way to remove the notification, when the user clicks on the notification.

Comment: You can use setAutoCancel() method, too. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setAutoCancel(boolean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically setting flags after notification has been put.

You need to swap the last two lines of the code you have provided. Set flags before calling nm.notify();

Comment: This is correct. Similarly, if you use Notification.Builder (or NotificationCompat.Builder as indicated by Shreya Shah's comment), make sure you call setAutoCancel() on the builder *before* you call .build().

Answer (score 1):

try this it works fine for me

```
--> notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
--> notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; 
notificationManager.notify(i, notification);
```

Comment: yes I can see, but try to replace your code with my code speciall lines marked with ---> sign.....

Comment: Its not working. it is removing the notification, next time a new notification is received.

Answer (score 1):

this is the prototype of the notification i used in one of my app

```
    Notification notification=new Notification(R.drawable.ic_stat_download_interrupted,getResources().getString(R.string.dint),System.currentTimeMillis());
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_download_complete);
    contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notimage, R.drawable.ic_stat_download_interrupted);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.nottext, getResources().getString(R.string.dint));
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.nottitle, update.initialDetail.fileName);

    notification.contentView = contentView;      
    notification.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainDashboard.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_SHOW_DOWNLOADS, true);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.contentIntent=contentIntent;

nm.notify(update.updateId.intValue(), notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

its working for me

notifyDetails.flags =Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanx for the response, but have you seriously looked at the question.? it is about how to remove notification, not to start the LED for this notification.